# How to get the Route's middleware name in laravel

Tags: laravel

If a route or group of the route is having an array of middleware applied to them. How can I get the middleware name in Exception/Handler.php?

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '/v1',
    'middleware' => ['api', 'secondMiddleware'], 
    'namespace' => 'Frnt\Folder'
], function () {
    // list page posts
    Route::GET('/posts{active?}{name?}', 'PostController@getPosts');      
});
```

What I want is a middleware name only LIKE 'api' and 'secondMiddleare', In Exception/Handler.php .

Comment: What's your plan exactly? Do you want to know how to create a middleware with a custom name like `secondMiddleware` or get all middlewares assigned to a route in your controller action?

Comment: Yes, I want to get all middlewares assigned to a route or a group in handler.php.

Comment: The exception `Handler.php`?

Comment: Yes, Exception/handler.php

Comment: @Dan, i want to achieve like this link, https://twitter.com/TheAlexLichter/status/969879256271597568 with the name of Andrés Herrera García

Comment: And where's the problem with that?

Comment: In Exception/Handler.php, I am unable to get the route name and the middleware name.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of all middleware used in your current route by using [`Route::middleware()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_middleware) and the `Route` facade:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getCurrentRoute()->middleware()
```

If you're inside a controller you can access the currently route via the injected `Request`:

```
public function someControllerAction(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $middleware = $request->route()->middleware();
}
```